# Using `.toggle()` rather than applying a class to show content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a simple website to use at a conference and I'm looking for some help understand the implications of two ways to achieve an effect:

**Using `.toggle()` to show or hide content**

This is the method I started with because it is an intuitive action to tap an element to have it's content appear. However, a problem arises when I try to limit one open div at a time.

Summary **I'm having trouble limiting the number of opened elements**.

---

**Applying an `active` class with jQuery**

Using this method, I can display the hidden content by selecting the child element (see code below), but this stops the user from closing the content by tapping it again. Because I'm expanding divs horizontally, this isn't ideal because of the scroll space that's added.

Summary: **How do you close the active div on a second click with this method?**

---

## [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/Irqpc) - [Staged site](http://dev.brianbennett.org/olc)

**Relevant Code**

This method is using CSS to apply the active class. It works, but like I said above, I'm having a hard time removing the `active` class from an element tapped again. Use the demo linked above to see how the toggle action works on the page (uncomment lines 8 and 9).

```
$(".title").click(function() {
     //remove active class from other elements
     $('.post').removeClass('active');
     // Bind to the div
     $post = $(this);
     // Set active class on .post to control scroll position
     $post.parent().toggleClass('active');
     // Toggles the hidden .content div
     //$post.next().toggle(250);
     $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: $('.active').offset().left},500);
});
```

The accompanying `.active` CSS:

```
.post .content {
  display:none;
}
.active {
  margin-top:-120px;
}

/* Shows the content div rather than toggling with jQuery */
.active > .content {
  display:block;
}
```

Is there a way I can allow both behaviors (tap to open/close, one open div at a time)? Which method is best suited for that?

Comment: _"I can't limit the number of opened elements."_ Why not?

Comment: Indeed, JQ has multiple options for filtering elements

Comment: Statement was unclear...updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can use `toggle()` while hiding the other ones. Try something like this:

```
$(".title").click(function() {
  $('.post').not($(this).parent()).hide();
  $(this).toggle();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: $(this).parent().offset().left},500);
});
```

Update: changed `.not(this)` to `.not($(this).parent())` as `.title` is always child of `.post`.

Comment: `.title` is a child of `.post`, so your `.not(this)` shouldn't work, unless not accounts for parents of the passed element.

Comment: I ended up changing the `.hide()` method because all of the parent divs were hiding, but this led me to a working solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly optimised version of @Daniel's solution

```
$('.title').click(function() {
  var clickedPost = $(this).parent('.post')
  clickedPost.toggle().siblings('.active').hide();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: clickedPost.offset().left},500);
});
```

**Local var:** If you access `this`, or any other DOM element more than once inside a scope, it's always more efficient to assign it to a local var than wrap it in a JQ object multiple times.

**SIblings selector:** I don't have a benchmark for this, but running a selector on a subset of the DOM rather than the whole DOM seems intuitively faster. This is more best practice than a large performance hit, but all the little functions add up too.

**Chaining JQuery functions:** Most JQ functions that act on a JQ element return that element. I can't say that this is more efficient but it's certainly more concise, but this all depends on personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

With very little code you can do this with toggle.

```
$(".title").click(function() {
    $(".post").hide();
    $(this).children(".post").toggle();
});
```

I made it as simple as possible to show the functionality which you could then extend on.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/zn7vkb1r/)

**EDIT** update after comment

I have edited it to now only show 1 at a time and if the 1 currently being shown is clicked it hides it

I also elected to use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` as it seemed to better suit your needs

```
$(".title").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).children(".post").is(":visible")){
        $(this).children(".post").slideUp();
    }else{
        $(".post").not($(this).parent()).slideUp(500);
        $(this).children(".post").slideDown(500);
    }
});
```

updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/zn7vkb1r/1/)

Comment: This solution does not allow the user to close (toggle) a post by anew clicking of the element.